# SNICallback can be used without any browser?

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy, sni

I have to use SNICallback on my project for separate two HTTPS addresses on the same port.
One of the addresses is used for API calls like `https://api.myDomain.com/products` and between two computers without any browser.

But I've read the below sentence on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

> To make use of SNI practical, the vast majority of users must use web browsers that implement it.

Would it be possible '*using SNICallback without any browser?*'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of TLS clients that implements SNI would include clients that are browsers and clients that are not browsers.